# check if data is already present in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js

I have the following data with me.

```
var Inputdata = {};
Inputdata.firstName = 'Raul'
Inputdata.lastName = 'Peters'
```

I want to check if the firstName and lastName (together) is already present in the array of objects. Can someone please let me know how to achieve this.

```
UserData: [0] 
      firstName: 'Raul'
      lastName: 'Peters'
      Id: '4'
      [1]
      firstName: 'Amil'
      lastName: 'Rikia'
      Id: '5'
      [2]
      firstName: 'Riya'
      lastName: 'Pillai'
      Id: '6'
      [3]
      firstName: 'Natasha'
      lastName: 'Shacke'
      Id: '6'
      [4]
      firstName: 'Eric'
      lastName: 'Coles'
      Id: '6'
```

As you can see, Raul Peters is present in the array of objects in one array. I want the output to be true in this case. If Raul and Peters were in different objects, the answer should be false as Raul and Peters are not in the same object. Can anyone please let me know how to achieve this

Comment: Using a loop and checking their properties

Comment: [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: Use `Array#find`.

Answer (score 2):

Just do an `Array.some` check:

```
let isPresent = UserData.some(user => user.firstName == 'Raul' && user.lastName == 'Peters')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Array.find

```
arr.find( function(e){
   if(e.firstname == 'Raul' && e.lastname == 'Peters')
     return e;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const inputData = {};

inputData.firstName = 'Raul';
inputData.lastName = 'Peters';

const userData = [
  {
    firstName: 'Raul',
    lastName: 'Peters',
    Id: '4'
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Amil',
    lastName: 'Rikia',
    Id: '5'
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Riya',
    lastName: 'Pillai',
    Id: '6'
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Natasha',
    lastName: 'Shacke',
    Id: '6'
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Eric',
    lastName: 'Coles',
    Id: '6'
  }
];
```

This function receives 2 arguments: the `userData` array of objects and the `inputData` object. Then, it uses the `Array.prototype.some()` method to see if there is at least one entry within the `userData` array that is an object matching the `inputData` object.

```
function alreadyExists(userData, inputData) {
  return userData.some(entry => entry['firstName'] === inputData['firstName'] && entry['lastName'] === inputData['lastName']);
};

console.log(alreadyExists(userData, inputData));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna use underscore or lodash you can use function _.some. Using internal variable you can get needle element.

```
var needle = false;
var has = _.some(UserData, function(v) {
    return (v.firstName===Inputdata.firstName && v.lastName===Inputdata.lastName) ? needle = v : false;
});
console.log(has)
console.log(needle)
```